# Consulta utilizando order by com lentidao

Tags: postgresql

Possuo uma query assim:

```
select ae_id from app_event
join trip_item on ti_id = ae_trip_item_id
where ae_driver_id = 63 order by ae_date desc limit 10;
```

A tabela `app_event` possui cerca de 3milhoes de dados, e a tabela `trip_item` possui cerca de 1milhao.

O retorno e cerca de 40mil dados, e acredito que o problema seja em ordenar todos esses dados, alem do `join` entre duas tabelas grandes. Eu utilizei [isso](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-ordering.html) para colocar um index no `ae_date` (coluna do `order by`), porem nao ajudou muito. Como posso realizar uma consulta mais rapida ?

Comment: Já rodou um analyze pra ver as estimativas de tempo e porque ta demorando tanto?

Comment: acho que pode adicionar índices para as colunas que fazem o join também. Faça o select com um explain antes. `explain select ae_id from app_event
join trip_item on ti_id = ae_trip_item_id
where ae_driver_id = 63 order by ae_date desc limit 10;` e veja em qual etapa o tempo é maior

Comment: @MatheusMordorst nao usei o analyze, porem vi pelo Explain query que o order by levava mais tempo para ser executado.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis elas ja possuem indexes, tambem sao sao PK e FK todas elas (tirando ae_date, ai adicionei um index nela)

Comment: É normal um ORDER BY demorar tanto para ser feito com essa quantidade de dados, já tentasse utilizar cache de query, ou é inviável pra teu caso?

Comment: dá uma olhada nesse artigo: https://imasters.com.br/artigo/4406/postgresql/otimizando-bancos-postgresql-parte-01/?trace=1519021197&source=single e confira a opção `work_mem`

Comment: @FabianoLothor eu nunca utilizei a cache. Eu tenho varios motoristas que mandam `eventos` para o banco todos os dias, entao os dados das tabelas tentem a aumentar. E os responsaveis desses motoristas fazem essas consultas, diariamente. Eu nao sei se nesse caso daria para utilizar a cache

Comment: Ja pensou em utilizar essa query em um view? se que vc tem permissão para isso.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiramente foi criado um cenário semelhante ao que você descreveu: estrutura idêntica e uma massa de dados aleatória:

```
--
-- MODELO DA TABELA app_event
--
create table app_event
(
  ae_id serial primary key,
  ae_driver_id integer,
  ae_trip_item_id integer,
  ae_date timestamp not null
);

--
-- MODELO DA TABELA trip_item
--
create table trip_item
(
  ti_id serial primary key
);

--
-- INSERE 3 MILHOES DE REGISTROS NA TABELA app_event
--
INSERT INTO app_event( ae_id, ae_date, ae_driver_id, ae_trip_item_id )
SELECT
    generate_series( 1, 3000000 ),
    now() - ((random() * 3650) * '1 day'::interval),
    (random() * 100)::int,
    (random() * 100)::int;
--
-- INSERE 1 MILHAO DE REGISTROS NA TABELA trip_item
--
INSERT INTO trip_item( ti_id )
SELECT
    generate_series( 1, 1000000 );
```

Query em análise:

```
SELECT
    ae_id
FROM
    app_event
JOIN
    trip_item ON (ti_id = ae_trip_item_id)
WHERE
    ae_driver_id = 63
ORDER BY
    ae_date DESC
LIMIT
    10;
```

O plano da sua query fica mais ou menos assim:

```
Limit  (cost=87050.55..87050.58 rows=10 width=12)
  ->  Sort  (cost=87050.55..87089.49 rows=15574 width=12)
        Sort Key: app_event.ae_date
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=28320.00..86714.00 rows=15574 width=12)
              Hash Cond: (app_event.ae_trip_item_id = trip_item.ti_id)
              ->  Seq Scan on app_event  (cost=0.00..58043.59 rows=15574 width=16)
                    Filter: (ae_driver_id = 63)
              ->  Hash  (cost=15045.00..15045.00 rows=1062000 width=4)
                    ->  Seq Scan on trip_item  (cost=0.00..15045.00 rows=1062000 width=4)
```

Repare que o analisador de plano aponta dois pontos de atenção:

**1)** Um `Sequential Scan` com um `cost` bastante elevado na tabela `app_event` por causa de uma filtragem pelo campo `ae_driver_id`;

**2)** Outro `Sequential Scan` com um `cost` bastante elevado na tabela `trip_item` por causa da condição de join utilizando o campo `ae_trip_item_id`.

Uma busca sequêncial em uma tabela com um grande volume de dados tende a ser lenta durante as operações de leitura. Por isso a criação de índices é crucial para uma boa performance.

Criando Índices:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ae_trip_item_id ON app_event (ae_trip_item_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_ae_driver_id ON app_event (ae_driver_id);
```

Novo plano da query:

```
Limit  (cost=24050.07..24050.09 rows=10 width=12)
  ->  Sort  (cost=24050.07..24120.51 rows=28178 width=12)
        Sort Key: app_event.ae_date
        ->  Merge Join  (cost=23021.55..23441.15 rows=28178 width=12)
              Merge Cond: (trip_item.ti_id = app_event.ae_trip_item_id)
              ->  Index Only Scan using trip_item_pkey on trip_item  (cost=0.42..30408.42 rows=1000000 width=4)
              ->  Sort  (cost=23014.70..23085.14 rows=28178 width=16)
                    Sort Key: app_event.ae_trip_item_id
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on app_event  (cost=530.81..20932.02 rows=28178 width=16)
                          Recheck Cond: (ae_driver_id = 63)
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_ae_driver_id  (cost=0.00..523.76 rows=28178 width=0)
                                Index Cond: (ae_driver_id = 63)
```

O efeito da criação de indices é a ausência total de `Sequential Scans` no plano da query e uma redução drástica no `cost` das operações.

Na prática, em meus testes, antes da criação dos índices, a query demorava `450ms` para ser executada, após a criação dos índices o tempo de execução fica em torno de `12ms`.

Espero ter ajudado!